# Table lines and alignment problem

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating, multirow

I'm using `sidewaystable` environment with the following configuration:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{6cm} | m{14cm} |}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Envelope \#{}1} \\[1cm] \hline
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{10-Envelope1}} & \textbf{Thermal Variables} \\[1cm]
    & Surface-to-Volume Ratio \hspace{1cm} Fenestration \hspace{1cm} Shading\vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Simulation Programme} \\[1cm]
         &  \vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Generative Algorithm} \\[1cm]
         & \vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Performative Algorithm} \\[1cm]
         \emph{Ensifacopa Planorstripat} &  \vspace{0.5cm}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

when I compile, this is what I get:

[image: compiled document]

My questions are:

1. Why are the table boundaries open at the top
2. Why don't the columns align to the centre despite using `{|m{6cm}|m{14cm}|}`
3. I don't know why, but I have to use `\cline` to split the table, it's like I'm not even using `\multirow`.

Answer (score 1):

`m` columns and `\\[...]` don't combine quite as one might hope. Also don't use `[h]` on tables, LaTeX almost always issues a warning about that and changes it to `ht`.  It is better to use `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight`. I added `demo` as I didn't have the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htp]\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}\setlength\extrarowheight{.3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{6cm} | m{14cm} |}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Envelope \#{}1} \\ \hline
    \multirow{7}{*}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{10-Envelope1}} & \textbf{Thermal Variables} \\
    & Surface-to-Volume Ratio \hspace{1cm} Fenestration \hspace{1cm} Shading\vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Simulation Programme} \\
         &  \vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Generative Algorithm} \\
         & \vspace{0.5cm}\\ \cline{2-2}
         & \textbf{Performative Algorithm} \\
         \emph{Ensifacopa Planorstripat} &  \vspace{0.5cm}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```